# JavaScript-friendly alternative to the f(x) = y JScript idiom that's used when setting CDO.Message options

Tags: javascript, email, asp-classic, cdo.message

I have an ASP page written in JScript that sends e-mails using CDO.Message. For specifying an SMTP server (and other options) I'm doing something like this:

```
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item(
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") =
    "smtp.example.com";
```

Now, here comes the catch. I have this code in a stand-alone include file that I include in an HTML page as JavaScript so that I can run unit tests against it in a browser (using JsUnit etc.). I have JavaScript mock objects (Server, Request, etc.) that create a mock ASP environment for the included JScript code. The only problem I have left is with the CDO.Message option setting. Since the `f(x) = y` syntax that's used in the above code excerpt is not valid JavaScript (invalid left-hand operand), I can't run this piece of code (as it is) within a browser. I'm currently simply bypassing it in my unit test with a conditional that detects whether the environment is truly ASP.

I don't think that there's a JavaScript workaround to this. I'm looking for an alternative syntax (that may use the ActiveX interfaces differently) to setting CDO.Message options that would also be syntactically valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer when looking at the C++ code example at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526318(EXCHG.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526318%28EXCHG.10%29.aspx).

The solution is to make the assignment explicitly to the `Value` property:

```
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item(
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver").Value =
    "smtp.example.com";
```

This way, the code above is valid JavaScript than can be tested with a mock Configuration object.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem when writing server-side Javascript for IIS, That `f(x) = y` syntax was failing in my IDE's syntax checker. The solution I found helpful was JScript conditional comments like so:

```
f(x)/*@cc_on@if(0)*/[0]/*@end@*/ = y;
```

It puts the subscript index [0] on the end *except* when running in Microsoft's JScript engine. But, admittedly my solution is a bit hacky. I think in most cases yours is cleaner, so thanks for sharing it.

-Simon